# PHP reading first line of each file. *output overwrites the previous line*

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to read a text file line-by line.
I added a condition where if the first word is not "insert", skip it, but if "insert is the first word", print it out.

Here is the code:

```
$matching = "^insert";

$file = fopen("test.sql.text", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($file))
  {

        if(eregi($matching, fgets($file)) ){
        echo fgets($file)."<br />";
        } else
        echo "invalid beginning value <br />";

  }
fclose($file);
```

I have two lines in a file both beginning with "insert".  For some reason, it seems to over write the first insert with the second insert.
I would like to be able to print out any line that begins with an insert.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$line = fgets($file);

if(stripos($line, 'insert') === 0){
    echo $line . '<br />';
} else {
    echo 'invalid beginning value <br />';
}
```

In your code you've read the line in `if()` and if it matches the condition you asked php to read **one more line**

ps: regular expressions is an overengineering here, `stripos` is enough to check if the line starts with some substring.

Comment: Good catch. I used to make mistakes like this all the time.